# How does one see currents as solutions to continuity equations?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, reference-request, linear-pde

I often hear people say that the solution to the continuity equation is a current or can be viewed as a current but I never understood how exactly one can rewrite a continuity equation to make use of one such formulation.

Given a vector field
$$
b:\mathbb{R}^{n+1}\to\mathbb{R}^n
$$
We want to find curves of measure that solves the distributional equation
$$
\frac{d}{dt} \mu_t+\mathrm{div}(b_t\mu_t).
$$
I do understand that one can abstractly say that the above is a requirement on the boundary of a 1-current over space-time, i.e. a current $$T:\Omega_c(\mathbb{R}^n\times\mathbb{R})\to\mathbb{R}$$
Which is represented by
$$T=\int_\mathbb{R} (1\ \ b_t)\mu_t$$
And satisfies
$$\partial T=0.$$

What I do not understand is how one can make use of this formulation and obtain solutions or even if this is the formulation people speak about.

Even just a reference where I can look up this kind of presentation would be nice.